# Getting the rowindex and columnindex of a datagridview using its value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, indexing

Using this code, I can find the exact location of the cell value I specified,

```
Dim value As String = "apple"
Dim _DisplayText_ As String = ""
Dim _row_ As Integer = 0 : Dim _col_ As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.RowCount - 1
        If Me.DataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value = value Then
            _DisplayText_ = Me.DataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(i).Tag
            _row_ = j
            _col_ = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Is there any way not to use this nested loop? imagine if the rows of the datagridview is a thousands of data...that would be soooo slooowww.

is there a builtin function similar to this?

```
msgbox(dtg.findrow("apple"))
msgbox(dtg.findcol("apple"))
```

**EDIT**

I modified my loop and change it to this,

```
   Dim value As String = "apple"
   Dim _DisplayText_ As String = ""
   Dim _col_ As String = "colFruits"
   Dim _row_ As Integer = 0 : Dim _col_ As Integer = 0
   For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.RowCount - 1
       If Me.DataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(_col_).Value = value Then
           _DisplayText_ = Me.DataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(_col_).Tag
           _row_ = j
           _col_ = i
           Exit For
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: This approach is already pretty efficient. You might improve it by focusing the analysis on the "specific area you want" (e.g., the given column where the cell is expected to be). You might reduce (a bit) the size of the code by relying on a LINQ-based approach, but it will, most likely, deliver an equivalent performance (or even worse). Loops look messy and unefficient but actually are right the contrary.

Comment: PS: you need a further "Exit For" in the outer loop (inside a condition on the lines _row_ >= 0 and _col_ > 0). Also you should set the starting values for row/col to something "invalid", like -1.

Comment: PS2: why you think that iterating through 1000 lines will take too long? (1000 is too much for a computer?!) Additionally, how do you think that functions work? They need to check all the data (in case of having the function you are after or of relying on LINQ, a kind of looping would be involved anyway).

Comment: Varocarbas said it first but yeah, Loops look messier than Linq or using Hash Tables but they are actually . Check this out - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144456/does-linq-require-significantly-more-processing-cycles-and-memory-than-lower-lev

Comment: I used to filter by its column, and its pretty good...but I am not sure it will be fast when the data is pretty large in numbers...When the database is located from another computer (desktop w/ dongle) and the connection we use is wifi, I experience a slow process when retrieving the data. But then it works. Thanks!